# Get all the VBA macros of a workbook by VSTO

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

In VBA, we could use for example [Wb.VBProject.VBComponents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443982(v=vs.60).aspx) to fetch all the VBA macros of a workbook `Wb`.

Does anyone know if VSTO provides any object or function to access that?

**Edit 1:** Following the answer of Jim, I have got the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop` in your project.  You can then use

```
Imports Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
```

.
.

```
Dim components As VBComponents =  Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
```

or

```
Dim components As VBComponents = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
```

and then

```
For Each comp As VBComponent In components

Next
```

**EDIT:**

I created the following method in C# to get a list of Macros and add them to a `List<string>`

```
private static void GetMacros()
{
    int startLine = 0;
    vbext_ProcKind ProcKind;
    List<string> macros = new List<string>();

    VBComponents components = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents;
    try
    {
        foreach (VBComponent comp in components)
        {
            startLine = comp.CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1;
            while (startLine <= comp.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
            {
                string macroName = comp.CodeModule.get_ProcOfLine(startLine, out ProcKind);
                macros.Add(macroName);
                startLine += comp.CodeModule.get_ProcCountLines(macroName, ProcKind);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `Dim components As VBComponents =  Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents` is VBA statement, right? Please see the update in the OP... How could I add a reference to assembly Microsoft.Vbe.Interop...?

Comment: It looks like you tried doing this in the add-in `Startup` event.  The `ActiveWorkbook` wouldn't be available at this point.  I actually built an add-in and tested this by using a button click event.  You would probably want to do this in after the Workbook is open.  Perhaps in the Workbook [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.startup.aspx) event.

Comment: You should be able to add the reference from the Project.

Comment: Actually, I could now add the reference, as a result the build does not raise any error for `VBComponents components = Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents;`. I am investigating how to get the VBA code from `components`.

Comment: Thank you... I have written by myself VBA to do this, which should be similar to that page. But I am beginner to C# and VSTO, I will see if we could do this easily in C#...

Comment: @SoftTimur - I updated my answer with a  C# method to retrieve a list of macros.  It will add the macro names to a `List<string>`.